# Memory limitation on 6th intel CPU

Tags: memory, motherboard, intel-core-i7, ddr

Most systems with 6th gen cpu currently available (Dell X8900-3569BLK, Lenovo 700-90ED0007US) have 4 slots of DDR4 and limited to 32GB(I talked to live chat agents, checked www.crucial.com compatible memmory). I do not understand how this possible.
1. All mother boards on market with 6th chipset and 4 DDR4 have 64GB ([MB with 4 slots](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&output=search&tbm=shop&q=mother%20board&oq=mother%20board&gs_l=products-cc.3..0i10l10.1801.4125.0.4513.12.11.0.1.1.0.147.1180.5j6.11.0....0...1ac.1.64.products-cc..0.12.1175.dUTbAnLKaGM#hl=en&tbs=vw:l,mr:1,cat:289,pdtr0:713648%7C869366,pdtr1:972458%7C4.0%244.0&tbm=shop&q=mother%20board))
2. 6th gen cpu support 64GB (thats the main reason for me to buy it)
3. there are DIMM modules of 16GB Non ECC (desktop memory) http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/g11cd/CT7972439

My question is: Should I try my luck and put 64GB RAM into them or wait?

Comment: Are you having concerns with one of those specific systems and their memory limitations, or are you just asking why some motherboards can have more RAM than others?

Comment: I want to understand. How they can limit RAM it with example(its not mother board because there are no mother board on market with these limitations).

Comment: 64GB of RAM will work fine. Other than the number of slots it's actually nothing to do with the motherboard. OEMs just quote the highest they've actually tested and certified it with at time of release.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq What about some physical limitation on memory lanes as txtechhelp mentioned?

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Is there are chance of damaging system by putting not allowed amount of memmory? (Do not want to burn my $600 dimms)

Comment: @yura the chance of you damaging the system by putting wrong RAM in it is tiny (unless you force it into a slot which was not designed to physically accommodate the RAM, or don't take precautions and it gets damaged due to static - but that applies to any memory)

Comment: @qasdfdsaq In addition to the possible memory lanes limitation, there could well be BIOS type limitations.

Comment: @yura: They don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what kind of motherboards are in either of those systems, but given their price point, it's a safe bet that they are not the higher end motherboards that have the 'upgrader' in mind (i.e. they want you to buy more system instead of get 2 extra sticks of RAM). And just because a chipset/CPU can support X amount of RAM, doesn't mean that the motherboard physically has to (which is probably the case here).

It's possible the systems could have a hard limit in the BIOS that could be removed with a non-stock image (at the risk of voiding your warranty or system instability), and it's also possible the motherboard manufacture (most probably Dell and Lenovo's MB offshoot company) put a physical imitation on the memory lanes or something of the like, either to save money in production costs or as a specific design decision (thermal issues, etc.).

So to answer your actual question:

> Should I try my luck and put 64GB RAM into them or wait?

If you already have the 64GB of RAM, you won't recognize more than 32 on one of those systems but you might have a chance if something like a BIOS update can fix that (though I doubt they'd double from 32-64 over a BIOS update), so chances are you'll be stuck at 32GB on one of those systems. And I'm not sure what you'd 'wait' for other than to build a different system with a different motherboard.

I hope that can add some clarity.

Comment: That's make sense. I was hoping that it is very unlikely to have physical limitation. And the only reason they saying 32GB is max is because they only have 8GB Dimms at the moment.  Also as I showed there are no motherboards on the market which have such limitation. Seems like my options are:  1. buy one of these systems for $1000 and memory  for $600 and refund if it does not work. 2. replace motherboard later. (I am not the one who can assemble computer on my own)

Comment: @yura, option 1 would be the most reasonable given the circumstances. As I stated though, there's a good chance only 32GB will be recognized, but once you have the system in possession, you can crack open the case and do some searching on the MB serial number and you might be able to find out more specifics on how you can up the RAM (if possible). "Stock" systems like those don't always have the exact same MB's through out their line (for various reasons), so you'll have to do a trial-error ..